# Stuck when trying to manually implement the pop method for lists

Tags: python, list

**What I intended to do:**

> Implement a function called my_pop(), which is similar to the list
>   pop() method. Take a list as input, remove the last object from the
>   list and return it.

**What I came up with:**

```
# take an input of list;
# if not last item(determined by comparing index number): loop through the list and copy every item to new list
# if last item: pass

def my_pop(l):
    new = []
    l = list(l)
    for i in l:
        if l.index(i) == -1:
            pass
        else:
            new.append(i)
    return new
```

**Problem:** when run, it returns the list `new` as an exact copy of the old list `l`, failing to remove the last item of `l`; I haven't been able to figure out why my way don't work. General pointers greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**Solution:** 
thanks to the excellent answers below, I got to see why `if l.index(i) == -1` won't work; Pasted here is a similar solution based on @jh314 's insight, but using a while loop instead:

```
# take an input of list;
# compare the index using c to determine if it's the last element in the list;

def pop(l):
    n = []
    l = list(l)
    c = 0
    while c < int(len(l)-1):
        n.append(l[c])
        c = c + 1
    else:
        pass

    return n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the last element's index (the result of l.index(i) where i is the last element of your list), does not equal -1.

This is a potential fix:

```
def my_pop(l):
    new = []
    l = list(l)
    for i in l:
        if l[-1] == i:
            pass
        else:
            new.append(i)
    return new
```

Or even better:

```
def my_pop(l):
    return l[:-1]
```

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you! But I'm just curious about the `-1`: if I index the last element in a list `l`,I can use `l[-1]` right? (say `a=[1,2,3]`, `a[-1]` would be 3); so could you tell me why it won't work in my code?

Comment: But at the same time I see your point about why the last element isn't `-1` when counting forwards;it should be `len(l)-1`

Comment: When you enter this: `print l.index(i)`, the result will be a non-negative integer, so `l.index(i) == -1` will always be false (you are simply comparing a nonnegative integer with -1 at this point), so you will append every element of l to new.

Comment: Cool!  So is your question answered, or is there anything else that you are not sure about?

Comment: just selected as answer~ sorry was editing my question to include a solution. Thanks again for answering!

Comment: the shorter version at the end is very pythoniac!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. The `pop` function returns not the new list, but the last element of the old list - it looks like your function is returning the new list.
2. The index function always returns a positive index - remember that why you can access the last element of a list as -1, its real index is `len(l)-1`. Further, what happens if the last element is identical to another element in the list?

   > > > [1,2,3,1].index(1)

   What do you think this expression evaluates to? Oops!
3. I spoke of a "old" list and a "new" list, but they're really both the same list! Your code returns a modified copy of the list, but the old list remains the same. You can fix that by using a something like `del`, which modifies the list in-place.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def my_pop(lst):
        if len(lst) <= 1 : # "if last item: pass"
            return
        last_item_in_list = lst[-1] # that is what we want to return 
        del lst[-1] 
        # deletes an an item from a list 
        # (see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement )
        #
        return last_item_in_list
```